# Area of ​an inscribed triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

How to algebraically demonstrate that the statement below is false? A triangle always occupies more than a quarter of the area of ​​the circle it circumscribes.

Visually, it is easy to see that the statement is false, but I would like an algebraic demonstration using plane geometry

I try:

[image]

$b=2R$

$S_\triangle ABC = \frac{2R.h}{2}=R.h$

$S\triangle ABC: =\dfrac{abc}{4R} < \dfrac{\pi R^2}{4} \implies \dfrac{ac}{2} < \dfrac{\pi R^2}{4}$

$Rh=\dfrac{ac}{2}\implies ac = 2Rh \implies Rh < \dfrac{\pi R^2}{4} $

???

Comment: Instead of "the circle it circumscribes" = its incircel, you certainly mean "its circumscribed circle"

Comment: @petaarantes Note that, with $\measuredangle ABC = 90^{\circ}$, then $\triangle ABC$ is a right-angled triangle, and also $AC$ is the diameter of the circumscribed circle, as is seemingly indicated in your diagram.

Comment: Let $\def\circle{\bigcirc}\triangle ABC$ be any triangle of positive area $S_{\triangle ABC}$, and let $S_\circle$ be the positive area of its circumcircle $\circle$.
Pick a natural number $n$ such that $n>\frac{4S_{\triangle ABC}}{S_\circle}$.
Let $D$ be the point on segment $AC$ such that $AD:AC=1:n$, let $\ell$ be the line parallel to $AB$ through $D$, let $E$ be a point of intersection of $\ell$ and $\circle$ (Q: why do they intersect?).
Then $\circle$ is also circumcircle of $\triangle ABE$ and
$$ S_{\triangle ABE}=\frac 1n S_{\triangle ABC}<\frac 14S_\circle.$$

Comment: @JohnOmielan  Yes..I know it is a right-angled triangle,e but how do I use it for the demonstration?

Comment: @petaarantes One way, that involves relatively simple algebra, is to choose a [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) where the ratio of the hypotenuse to the shortest side is sufficient large. Out of curiosity, I already checked that $(5,12,13)$ works since $S\triangle ABC = \frac{5\cdot 12}{2}=30$, while the area of the circumscribed circle is $\pi\left(\frac{13}{2}\right)^2$, so the ratio is $\frac{30}{132.732\ldots}=0.226\ldots\lt 0.25$. Of course, there are also many other similar counter-examples.

Comment: All you need to do is find a counterexample. Just choose $h=R/2$. Then you have $R^2/2<\pi R^2/4$.

Comment: By Thale's Theorem, three vertices of a triangle with two falling on the ends of a diameter form a right triangle where the diameter is the hypotenuse. It follows the area is $(1/4)R^2 \sin{2\theta}$. The maximum occurs when the acute angles of the triangle are equal yielding an area of $R^2/4$, only a fraction of the quarter area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in your diagram, consider the right-angled $\triangle ABC$ where $\measuredangle ABC = 90^{\circ}$, so $AC$ is the hypotenuse, and with $\lvert AC\rvert = R$. Its circumscribed circle $\Large\circ$ then has a diameter of $R$.

Let $0 \lt m \le 0.5$ be the multiplier of $R$ that is the height of the triangle from $AC$, i.e., we have

$$h = mR$$

Then

$$\left(\frac{S_{\triangle ABC}}{S_{\Large\circ}} = \frac{\left(\frac{(mR)R}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{\pi R^2}{4}\right)}\right) \le \frac{1}{4} \iff \frac{2m}{\pi} \le \frac{1}{4} \iff m \le \left(\frac{\pi}{8} \approx 0.3927\right)$$

gives the set of values of $m$ which provide counter-examples to

> A triangle always occupies more than a quarter of the area of ​​the circle it circumscribes.